# Enumerate dynamic members (and values) in a Simple.Data.SimpleRecord

Tags: c#, dynamic, simple.data

I was trying to do some mapping with a Simple.Data.SimpleRecord and tried to iterate through the members:

```
foreach (string memberName in Model.GetDynamicMemberNames())
{
    Console.Write Model.GetValueByMemberName(memberName); // or something
}
```

GetDynamicMemberNames() works fine - but I dont find a GetValueByMemberName(), Member[].Value or similar. It is a DynamicObject, so perhaps there's some built in method I'm missing.

PS I miss a SimpleData tag here. It's going to be big :-) https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah - just cast it do a dictionary:

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)Model)["id"]
```

Case closed.